# create parent child array from inline data in php

Tags: php, arrays

actually i have simple problem but i forget how to solve it.. :D
i have data on table with following format
`01 Johson 01 Craig` 
`01 Johson 02 Daniel`
`01 Johson 03 Abbey` 
`02 Dawson 01 Brown` 
`02 Dawson 02 Agust` 
`03 Brick  01 Chev` 
`03 Brick  01 Flinch`

so i want it to become an array like this 
`01 Johson => 01 Craig`
``````````````` ``````````````02 Daniel ```````````````
```````````````` ```````````````03 Abey ````````````````
`
etc...
how to iterate trough the data and make it array like that...
i'm newby in PHP :))

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get the outcome, though I am partial to using a [mysql group concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select 
    col1, 
    group_concat(col2) as col2 
from 
    tableName 
group by 
    col1;
```

This will return that particular column of data in a comma delimted string, which you can then very easily [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) inside your PHP code as it comes from the database.

Even though a comma is the default for group_concat, you can easily change it to concat the rows of data on a different string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
  $parent = $row['parentid'].' '.$row['parentname'];
  if (!array_key_exists($parent, $results)) {
    $results[$parent] = array();
  }
  $results[$parent][] = $row['childid'].' '.$row['childname'];
}
```